# Complex Contour Integrals from integrals from $0 \to 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1 + x^3}$$

The bounds are not from 0 to infinity or from -infinity to infinity etc..

How can we use complex contour integration for this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to break the fraction by using $1+x^3=(1+x)(1-x+x^2)$ ?

Comment: I know it can be done using real methods, I am looking for complex methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the bounds:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^3} \stackrel{\left( x= \frac{1}{t+1}\right)}{=} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{t+1}{(t+1)^3+1}\text{d}t$$

I haven't checked if the latter one is solvable using complex contor integration. But I dont  see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Well, for one you'll have to be very careful when choosing your integration path and then for evaluating it, as $\;t=-2\;$ is a pole.

Comment: Even with the substitution, how does the the upperbound become infinity?

Comment: @Timbuc, is right, $t=-1$ is a pole, but it isnt in our interval. So by Cauchy's integral theorem, the contour integral $$\oint_{C} = 0$$ so we must evaluate the other parts?

Comment: @Amad27 The pole is at $\;z=-2\;$ , and it could be possible to choose a contour that includes the fourth quadrant, where one of the poles is found:  $\;-\frac12(1+\sqrt3\,i)\;$

Comment: @Timbuc, how is that a pole?

Comment: @Amad27 Substitute, simply. I, of course, am talking *after* the proposed substitution of detervdf.

Comment: @Timbuc Yeah, i guess the poles would be quite messy... Messy but not impossible i guess. The poles are located at $$z=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}(1+2k)}\qquad k \in \{ 0,1,2\}$$ You could use a semi-circle with a smaller semi-cirle at $z=-2$.

Comment: but how is the upperbound infinity?

Comment: Have you tried the substitution? What does this result into?

Comment: Ok, I see you took $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x$ to get infinity